# OSError: [Errno 30] Read-only file system: <relative_path_to_file>

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, hard-drive, file-permissions, read-only

(On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS)

When trying to create or edit any file or directory on my hard drive I get a 'Read-only file system'-error (two days ago I could still do that):

```
$ whoami
mattia
$ mkdir example
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘example’: Read-only file system
```

My permissions for any directory on the drive are as follows:

```
drwxrwxrwx 1 mattia mattia    0 Jan  1  2022  example
```

For files it is:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mattia mattia  314 Jan  2  2022  example.txt
```

Can someone explain to me what is happening and how I could resolve this issue?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your filesystem is probably mounted read-only.
you can use `mount` to list all the mounted volumes on your system with their flags (rw) for read-write and (ro) for read-only filesystems.